# Multidimensional array memory allocation in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

One dimensional arrays consume memory on heap in contiguous memory blocks.

But

When we create the multidimensional array how they are allocated memory?

What is the mechanism of allocating memory to multidimensional arrays?